# How to replace numpy.nan to -1 (in one line of code)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have `z = np.array([4.4, 3, 0, np.nan, -1, 6])` and just can't find any quick and friendly solution for easy replacement. I can't believe it's sometimes such not user friendly language.

I tried:

`np.where(z == np.nan, -1, z)`

nothing happens

`np.nan_to_num(z, -1)`

changes to zeros

`z = [-1 if np.nan(x) else x for x in z]`

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Why such earsy things can't be just as pure easy? I must use numpy only.

Comment: In your list comprehension, changing `np.nan(x)` to `np.isnan(x)` will work.  (Alternatively, and possibly faster, would be: `z[np.isnan(z)] = -1`).

Comment: Maybe it's duplicated but I also tried to show Python 4 needs to have better implementations for some base functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `np.isnan(x)`. You can replace like this:

```
z = np.array([4.4, 3, 0, np.nan, -1, 6])
z[np.isnan(z)] = -1
print(z)

# [ 4.4  3.   0.  -1.  -1.   6. ]
```

Comment: God bless you. Thanks for very quick response.